# using StreamReader.Read to read blocks of short, integer and decimal data types

Tags: c#, char, streamreader

the values are comma separeted so I am using a stringbuilder to build up the values. then write them to the appropriate buffer. I noticed a considerable time spent in the builder.ToString and the Parse functions. Do I have to write unsafe code to overcome this problem? and what's the best way to acheive what I want

```
   private static void ReadSecondBySecondFileToEndBytes(FileInfo file, SafeDictionary<short, SafeDictionary<string, SafeDictionary<int, decimal>>> dayData)
    {
        string name = file.Name.Split('.')[0];
        int result = 0;
        int index = result;
        int length = 1*1024; //1 kb
        char[] buffer = new char[length];

        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        bool pendingTick = true;
        bool pendingSymbol = true;
        bool pendingValue = false;
        string characterString = string.Empty;
        short symbol = 0;
        int tick = 0;
        decimal value;
        using (StreamReader streamReader = (new StreamReader(file.FullName)))
        {

            while ((result = streamReader.Read(buffer, 0, length)) > 0)
            {
                int i = 0;
                while (i < result)
                {
                    if (buffer[i] == '\r' || buffer[i] == '\n')
                    {                           
                        pendingTick = true;
                        if (pendingValue)
                        {
                            value = decimal.Parse(builder.ToString());
                            pendingSymbol = true;
                            pendingValue = false;
                            dayData[symbol][name][tick] = value;
                            builder.Clear();
                        }
                    }
                    else if (buffer[i] == ',') // new value to capture
                    {                          
                        if (pendingTick)
                        {
                            tick = int.Parse(builder.ToString());
                            pendingTick = false;
                        }
                        else if (pendingSymbol)
                        {
                            symbol = short.Parse(builder.ToString());
                            pendingValue = true;
                            pendingSymbol = false;
                        }
                        else if (pendingValue)
                        {
                            value = decimal.Parse(builder.ToString());
                            pendingSymbol = true;
                            pendingValue = false;
                            dayData[symbol][name][tick] = value;
                        }
                        builder.Clear();
                    }
                    else
                        builder.Append(buffer[i]);
                    i++;
                }

            }
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My suggestion would be to not try to parse the majority of the file as you are doing now, but go for something like this:

```
using (var reader = File.OpenText("<< filename >>"))
{
    string line;

    while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
    {
        string[] parts = line.Split(',');

        // Process the different parts of the line here.
    }
}
```

The main difference here is that you are not parsing line ends and separation on comma's. The advantage being that when you use high level methods like `ReadLine()`, the `StreamReader` (which `File.OpenText()` returns) can optimize for reading the file line by line. The same goes for `String.Split()`.

Using these high level methods will almost always be faster then when you parse the buffer yourself.

With the approach above, you don't have to use the `StringBuilder` anymore and can just get your values like this:

```
tick = int.Parse(parts[0]);
symbol = short.Parse(parts[1]);
value = decimal.Parse(parts[2]);
dayData[symbol][name][tick] = value;
```

*I have not verified the above snippet; please verify that these lines are correct, or correct them for your business logic.*

Comment: +1 ..I was using the ReadLine function, and doing exactly what you said using the string.split. This code is executed in parallel over like 100 files. So my colleague said that Reading blocks will minimize the switching between the different hardisk segments and yet give better performance! theoratically what he said made some sense, but in practice i didn't notice much improvement !

Comment: No it won't. `ReadLine()` will by default read with blocks of 1K, and you can increase this buffer size with an overload of the `StreamReader` constructor.

Answer (score 1):

You got the wrong impression.  Yes, while you are testing your program, you'll indeed see most time being spent inside the Parse() and builder.  Because that is the only code that does any real work.

But that's not going to be this way in production.  Then all the time will be spent in the StreamReader.  Because the file won't be present in the file system cache like it is when you run your program over and over again on your dev machine.  In production, the file has to be read off a disk drive.  And that's glacially slow, disk I/O is the true bottleneck of your program.  Making the parsing twice as fast will only make your program a few percent faster, if at all.

Don't compromise the reliability or maintainability of your code for such a small gain.

Comment: I agree with you. When I deployed the code on the server, I noticed that the reading is even taking more time although the server is high specs. In such a case where I/O is the bottleneck, is it advisable to go for solid state drives since there's not much code optimization that could be done?

Comment: Sure, you can throw hardware at the problem.  Is it really a problem?  Putting an SSD in a server sounds fairly risky to me.

Comment: Yes it is actually a problem as this code is executed in parralel over 100 files depending on some request. The thing is the files need to be in memory as fast as possible, and the results are not very promising (>8 secs).. The SSD provider (DELL) is claiming that it is even more stable than the normal SA TA drives cuz it contains no mechanical parts. this is just in theory.

Comment: Fix the process.  Why is this data in CSV and not a dbase?  That conversion can happen long before the request comes in.

Comment: cuz this is just compressed data. it's expanded in the memory according to some algorithm. Also, there's no such a fixed number of columns in the file data. 1 line could have 1 or 10's of values. however, the expanded data could be inserted to DB but this will occupy a really big storage size, and will again take big query time. Actually, the whole file thing is done to avoid the previous db usage

Comment: Hmm, think this through for a bit.  Sucks to throw a bunch of work away but if you added a bunch of complexity and it doesn't actually improve the process then you might be better off without it.  Not something I can help you with.  Good luck with it.